# How resistance is introduced in the transformer primary

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

I use a voltage source and a planar coil as a primary and a second planar coil as a secondary.
I understand that when secondary coil is brought in the vicinity of the primary coil, this induces currents inside the secondary coil. The reactance of the system decreases because secondary current is decreasing the magnetic field strength. This allows more current to flow trough the primary as impedance decreases.

The problem I have is that I don't understand how Ohmic resistance appears. What causes it to appear? As far as I see, the bigger percentage of the field passes trough the loops, the bigger the resistance. Now the confusing part is the following. When I add a resistor in series with the secondary coil, the overall resistance felt decreases. But when we use a material that has a higher resistance, the effect is the opposite, since resistance felt increases instead of decreasing.

So by what effect does resistance get introduced in the system (I know how reactance does)?

In induction heating, we try to increase the resistance of the material by increasing frequency (skin effect). But wouldn't increased resistance then decrease the resistance the coil feels? This isn't the case.

Comment: The answer is so elementary that I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly:  the resistance of the transformer primary is due simply to the non-zero resistivity of the wire.  Note that when you place a resistor across the secondary, you're not *adding* resistance to the secondary circuit, you're *lowering* the resistance *seen* by the secondary, i.e., you're placing a resistor in 'parallel' with an open circuit ('infinite' resistance).

Comment: Then why in induction heating, does incresing the resistance of the metal (by increasing frequency and with it reducing skin depth), make us see a bigger resistance on the primary, than with lower resistance?

Comment: MaDrung, honestly, I don't understand either your reasoning, your question, or both.  Put another way, I don't understand why my comment would lead you to your "Then why ..." question.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: It's because you say that increasing resistance of the secondary circuit reduces the resistance of the primary. But this isn't the case in induction heating, because increasing frequency makes resistance of the metal bigger. By your reasoning we hould see a decrease of resistance on the primary by this action. But we actualy see increase. It's the opposite what you said. Also the equation of calculating secondary resistance to the primary circuit says that if we increase the resistance of the secondary, we see increase of resistance of the primary.

Comment: *"It's because you say that increasing resistance of the secondary circuit reduces the resistance of the primary."* - full stop.  I did not write that *at all*.  Please take some time to look more carefully at what I wrote.

Comment: I've re-read your first comment and I don't understand how adding series resistance to a secondary circuit is not adding resistance to a secondary circuit and so making secondary resistance seen by the primary higher.

Comment: MaDrung, connecting a resistor *across* (please think about what that means) an open  secondary is not "adding series resistance to a circuit".  Think about it, if the secondary is open, the resistance is infinite and there is no secondary current and thus, there is no primary current, i.e., the source driving the primary 'sees' an open circuit.  Placing a resistor *across* the secondary allows secondary current which implies primary current and the source driving the primary sees a finite (versus infinite) resistance.

Comment: If I now place another resistor in series with the first, the resistance across the secondary *is* increased and the source driving the primary sees a greater resistance.

Comment: I see what the confusion is about, so I Will try to explain it better. I think you are wrong about this. You say that when the secondary is open, the resistance of the secondary is "infinite". I agree with this. Then I think you imply that because the secondary resistance is infinite, the primary resistance should also be infinite. This is NOT true. The resistance of the primary is smallest, when the secondary has an open circuit. What actualy happens is that primary reactance is quite bigger, but resistance is smaller. So the impedance is the biggest in this condition. ----> Part 2

Comment: Now consider a cloosed loop secondary with no resistor except its internal wire resistance. When I do this, the current in the secondary starts flowing. Because of phase shift, the secondary magnetic field acts to reduce the primary magnetic field, which reduces overal magnetic field, reducing the reactance. Because of this the current in primary increases even though the resistance actualy INCREASED when we reduced the secondary resistance, because it's not infinite anymore. When we add resistor in series with the secondary, we see decrease in primary resistance, instead of increase.

Comment: But in induction heating when we increase the resistance of the pot, we see bigger resistance on the primary. The equations also say that bigger secondary resistance leads to bigger primary resistance. This contradicts itself since different experiments give opposite results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68752/discussion-between-alfred-centauri-and-madrung).